# Is $x+\frac{d}{dx}$ differential operator diagonalizable?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, eigenfunctions, differential-operators

I would like to prove or disprove the following statement:

Let $T=x+\frac{d}{dx}$ be a differential operator. Then $T$ is diagonalizable under some initial/boundary condition.

Here is my attemp to find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of $T$:

$$Tf=\lambda f$$

$$xf+\frac{df}{dx}=\lambda f$$

$$\frac{df}{dx}=(\lambda - x)f$$

$$\frac{df}{f}=(\lambda-x)dx$$

By integrating on both sides:$$Lnf=(\lambda x -\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+ C_{0} )$$

$$f=e^{(\lambda x -\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+C_{0} )}$$

$$f=Ce^{(\lambda x -\frac{1}{2}x^{2})}$$

I do not know how to proceed from here. For instance, if I assume $f(0)=f(1)$, I obtain $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$ and $f(x)=Ce^{\frac{1}{2}(x - x^{2})}$. Does it say anything about $T$ being diagonalizable or not?

**Update:** what I mean by diagonalizable is that there exits an integral/differential operator $P$ such that T = $P^{-1}DP$ ($D$ is a diagonal operator). As an example see [this](https://www.science20.com/jon_lederman/fourier_transform_diagonalizing_convolution_operator) .

**Edit:** The domain of $T$ is the set of all differentiable functions defined on $[0,1]$ with $f(0) \neq 0$.

Comment: Provide definition of "diagonalizable" for infinite-dimensional operator $L$.  Note, $L$ maps a function space  to a function space, not $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thank you @GEdgar for the comment. You are right. I however renamed the operator from $L$ to $T$ to avoid confusion with $L^{2}$ integrable functions.

Comment: In infinite dimension, the domain of the operator is important and for different domains, you will get different eigenvalues and eigenvectors. In your case, you implicitly specify the domain (which is not $L_2$) to be the set of differentiable function $f$ such that $f(0)=f(1)$. This yields one single eigenvalue $\lambda=1/2$. If you pick $f(0)=0$, then there is no eigenvalue, and, finally, if $f(0)\ne 0$, you have infinitely many eigenvalues (uncountably).

Comment: Thank you @KBS . I just edited the question. Can we say that, in case of $f(0) \neq 0$, $T$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: Does this help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_and_annihilation_operators ?

Answer (score 1):

If we were dealing with linear algebra and finite matrices, this would be more clear. But we are not here. In particular, you haven't been clear by what you mean when you say "linear operator".

If by linear operator you mean an operator that sends polynomials to polynomials (which your operator does) and if by diagonalizable you mean that your operator possess an eigenvector of degree $n$ for each $n$, then it is easy to solve your problem. The answer is NO, $x+D$ is not diagolanizable. This is because there is no constant eigenvector. You can check, for any $c\not=0$, $T[c]=cx$ is also not a constant. In fact, there are no polynomial egienvectors. Another way to say this, is that there is no way to write the constant $1$ as a linear combination of vectors in the range of the linear operator, that is, there does not exist a basis of polynomials, $B_n(x)$, $\deg(B_n(x))=n$, $B_0\not=0$, and real numbers, $a_n$, such that $$1=a_0T[B_0(x)]+a_1T[B_1(x)]+\cdots$$

Again, you haven't been clear on what you are allowing for diagonalization. Or what the restrictions of your domain and range are for your operator. For example, you found the collection of all possible eigenvectors. Cool, tell me how to write $p(x)=x$ as a linear combinations of those eigenvectors. Moreover, are we regarding $p(x)$ as of infinite degree with respect to your choice of basis? Because, that isn't made clear by your statements. What are your restrictions? All possible differentiable functions? What is your domain, the uniform limit closure of your newly discovered eigenvectors? BTW, there do exist differnentiable functions with no second derivative anywhere; meaning while your domain may be differentiable functions, your range would not be.

I think you get the idea. Normally linear operators are defined on polynomials and convergently extended. If you instead want to talk about operators diagonalized by a non-polynomial basis, then you need to tell us the restrictions of that. If you simply leave it arbitrary, then it is anyone's guess what your domain and range are. It could very well be the case that your operator is not defined on polynomials at all if you choose some transcendental basis by which no polynomial can be successfully written as a summation of.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this:"If we were dealing with linear algebra and finite matrices, this would be more clear". What would be the answer?

Comment: When we think of linear operators, we typically think of a matrix. A diagonalizable operator is one with only diagonal entries. In the case of infinite dimensional spaces we can mimic the concepts of finite matrices and talk about infinite matricies. For example, if I have a linearly independent basis $B_n\not=0$ (meaning everthing in my domain is a lineanr combination of this), and an operator such that $T[B_n]=a_nB_n$, then we can "think" of $T$ as an infinite matrix with diagonals, $a_n$.

Comment: Thinking of the matrix in this way automatically requires us to be thinking of everything in the domain written as a linear combination of our chosen basis.

Comment: Suppose you have a basis, $B_n$ of infinitely differentiable functions, meaning that everything in your domain can be written as a linear combination if this basis. Since we allow infinite series we need a notion of convergence, we choose uniform convergence. If $f$ is the function that is differnentiable with no second derivative,  then $f$ can never be written in terms of the basis. The very concept of using $T$ on that function would make no sense.